Issue with 3D Sprite and Far DOF in GODOT 4.3
I'm working on a 3D project in Godot 4.3 and I'm struggling with Depth of Field (DOF) blurring my 3D sprites incorrectly. The sprites are getting blurred even though they're within the focus range, which is causing visual issues.
I read that enabling Opaque Pre-Pass in SpatialMaterial might fix this, but I'm having trouble even finding the SpatialMaterial in a 3DSprite in the first place. I've looked through the material settings in Godot 4.3, but I can't seem to locate where to access or configure this material and the Opaque Pre-Pass option.
Has anyone else had this issue, or can someone guide me on how to find and set up the SpatialMaterial with Opaque Pre-Pass in Godot 4.3? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
